# How to structure tables for television tracking?

Tags: sql, database, design-patterns, database-design, database-schema

I am working on an app that tracks which tv shows you are watching and which episodes from that show you have watched.

Currently I have can track which users are watching which shows, this is relatively simple and it is structured like so:

[table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEbWY.png)

So I have a `User` table which has a primary key `id` that identifies that user and some other info about that user which is not relevant.

Following this I have another table `TV_SHOWS` which stores a `user_id` as a foreign key some information about the show and crucially a field called `user_watching` that gives a boolean value as to whether the user is watching that show.

How it works is this, when the user clicks a button to add the show a row is inserted into the `TV_SHOWS` table with the all the information and `user_watching = true` at some point the user may wish to stop watching so they can click another button that will simply update the `user_watching = false`.

Now I wish to expand on this idea so that users can track which seasons and episodes of a tv show they have watched, a tv show is comprised many seasons and each season is comprised of many episodes in most cases.

I would like some help with how best to structure this database schema.

I initially thought that I could just expand along the same lines I had previously for instance:

I simply add two id's for the season and episode, in that way I can tell if a user has watched a season by seeing if they have watched all the episodes in that season and if they have watched a show by checking if they have watched all the seasons in the show, but I don't think this seems like good practice.

I could try and do a one table for shows, another for seasons and a final for episodes but I am not sure where I would "track" is a user had watched one of those, would it have to be in that specific table or would I need another table to track it?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: I think the latter design is a better option from a scalable design perspective.

Longer Answer:

The latter option with show <--> season <--> episodes separated into individual tables is closer to a textbook design.  [Third Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form), I think. The idea being that you want to reduce redundant data as much as possible, as to minimize storage space. Minimizing redundant data is a general best practice. By separating the three you are able to keep attributes that are specific to the each topic from being replicated.

For example, let's assume you track TV Show attributes like title, description or an average ranking.  If you maintain a single table with show/season/episode, then the TV Show attributes should technically be replicated (i.e. redundant) for every season and every episode in order to maintain a table constraints.  Conversely, separating out the TV show attributes avoids the redundant attribute data.  It also helps to allow the attributes set to grow/change overtime.

This design practice though comes with a computational cost as you need to JOIN the structures together depending upon the use cases.  For example, if you always need to know show title, season X, and episode title (attributes from each of the tables), then you'll need to develop the necessary join logic to obtain those attributes.  This cost can be mitigated using a View, which opens another set of decisions.

To your comment on the need for two keys. Following the three table design, you'll likely want a primary key of some sort on each table. If you structure the episode table with reference key to the season (and maybe the show), then you should only need to use the episode key as you can de-reference the season and TV show from the episode using join logic.  In effect, the episode should be enough to figure out the season and TV show from the linking.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- User USR exists.
--
user {USR}
  PK {USR}
```

```
-- TV show SHW exists.
--
show {SHW}
  PK {SHW}
```

```
-- Season number SEA# of show SHW exists.
--
season {SHW, SEA#}
    PK {SHW, SEA#}

    FK {SHW} REFERENCES show {SHW}
```

```
-- Episode number EPI# of season number SEA#
-- of show SHW, in duration of DUR_E minutes, exists.
--
episode {SHW, SEA#, EPI#, DUR_E}
     PK {SHW, SEA#, EPI#}

     FK {SHW, SEA#} REFERENCES season {SHW, SEA#}
```

```
-- User USR watched DUR_W minutes of episode number EPI#
-- of season number SEA# of show SHW.
--
user_show {USR, SHW, SEA#, EPI#, DUR_W}
       PK {USR, SHW, SEA#, EPI#}

    FK1 {SHW, SEA#, EPI#} REFERENCES
episode {SHW, SEA#, EPI#}

    FK2 {USR} REFERENCES user {USR}
```

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
FK = Foreign Key
```

```
Using suffix # to save on screen space.
OK for SQL Server and Oracle, for others use _NO.
For example, rename EPI# to EPI_NO.
```